# Azure DevOps Environment under useraccount with no password

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to setup some resources for an environment that we have in Azure DevOps. After generating and coping the script in the portal which will setup an agent on my machine you will be asked to specify under what account the agent should run. From the documentation you can read it is a good practice to use a separate account to run the actual agent

[Information security for self-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#:%7E:text=It%20is%20a%20best%20practice%20to%20have%20the%20identity%20running%20the%20agent%20be%20different%20from%20the%20identity%20with%20permissions%20to%20connect%20the%20agent%20to%20the%20pool.%20The%20user%20generating%20the%20credentials%20(and%20other%20agent%2Drelated%20files)%20is%20different%20than%20the%20user%20that%20needs%20to%20read%20them.)

*"It is a best practice to have the identity running the agent be different from the identity with permissions to connect the agent to the pool. The user generating the credentials (and other agent-related files) is different than the user that needs to read them."*

Now when i specify a user who is not an admin and has no password, I will still be prompted to specify a password. It is not possible to give an empty string here. Even if i add to the script the `--unattended` flag and add the `--password` flag without a value the script will fail since no value for a password is given.

Is it a requirement for the Azure Agent that user who run's the process/agent has a password on it's account?

[image: enter user password]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. As a general best practice, secure your accounts.